# increment/decrement transform rotation not working fiddle jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on this pie chart...

Anytime I click on red...the rounded absolute-positioned red `div` rotates an angles lower than 180 degrees to complete the another half according to the votes numbers...making the pie simulating this color correspond to the percentage of red votes.

**PROBLEM**

When I click on the red button the red div rotates correctly, but when clicking on the bue...it doesnt....

I'm currently testing the red size....so I want to make this work when the red sslice is 50% or greater (till 100%) out of the total size, once this works well it'll be added a blue positioned div to make the same for the blue side...

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var red=0;
var blue=0;
var Psum = (red+blue);
var r_rotation = 0;
var red_rotacion_control= 0;
$(".VoteMain").on("click",function(){ 


if($(this).hasClass("VoteRed")){
 red++;
 Psum = (red+blue);
 red_size_control = "increase_red";
 
}
 if($(this).hasClass("VoteBlue")){ 
 blue++; 
  Psum = (red+blue);
 red_size_control = "decrease_red";
}



var red_percentage= Math.floor((red/Psum)*100); 
var blue_percentage= 100-red_percentage;

///old +- new angles?
var sum_rotacion =  (1/(Psum-1) + 1/Psum)*360;
var rest_rotacion =  (1/(Psum-1) - 1/Psum)*360;


//display percentages
    $(".VoteRed span").text(red_percentage+"% :" +red+" votes > Votos Totales "+Psum);
    $(".VoteBlue span").text(blue_percentage+"% :"+blue);

 //rotate pieChart
if(red> blue){
//red mayor 
$(".red").css('z-index', 3000); 
$(".blue").css('z-index', 1);

if(red==Psum){
$(".red").rotate(180); 
}else{


if(red_size_control=="increase_red"){
 r_rotacion=(180-sum_rotacion);
 }else if(red_size_control=="decrease_red"){
  r_rotacion=(180-rest_rotacion);
  }



$(".red").rotate(r_rotacion);
}
 
}
 

 
});



//function
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    return $(this);
};
```

```css
.pie_container{
 
 margin:40px;

 
}
.pie{
 position:relative;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 qbackground:yellow;
 border-radius:50%;
 background-image:linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 0);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 
}
.blue{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 
 height:100px;
 width:50px;
 background:blue;
qborder:1px solid green;
 border-top-left-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;

  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.red{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 
 height:100px;
 width:50px;
 background:red;
border:1px solid yellow;
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;

  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
transform: rotate(0deg);

transition:all 1s ease-out;
}
.red span{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:20px;
}

.VoteMain{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie_container">

<div class="pie">
<div class="red"><span>b</span></div>
</div>

<div class="PollVoteMain">
<div class="VoteMain VoteBlue"><button>blue</button> <span>0</span></div>
<div class="VoteMain VoteRed"><button>red</button> <span>0</span></div>

</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the whole rotate calculation part to:

```
r_rotacion = (red_percentage / 100) * 360 - 180;
$(".red").rotate(r_rotacion);
```

The rotate is absolute not relative to the previous state

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nazrobvd/7/)

Comment: wow!! one of the best answers I received here in stackoverflow!! this one was a pretty tricky question...I started to overcalculating the rotation value without getting at anywhere.... full math..works perfect....thank you!!

Comment: Here there is a full working fiddle (red & blue) https://jsfiddle.net/nazrobvd/11/, it displays the slices with the correct size according their percentages....this need only a fix, a rotational fix, because after passing 50%, every slice shows the correct percentage but rotates at the opposite side of the previous rotation

Comment: yes bro! thank you...now I can add Yes/No polls to my site!.